# How to dismiss previous and current viewcontroller by click done button using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have three view controllers`(VC1, VC2, VC3)`. Here, VC1 add button click to present VC2 then VC2 I have another one add button for make a VC3 present. VC3 I have navigation bar `cancel` and `done` button. If I click I can able to dismiss and show VC2 but If I click done button I need to show VC1 (Between VC1 and VC3 need to dismiss VC2). How to achieve this?

I am using below code for presenting and dismissing

**VC1**

```
@IBAction func presentFirst(_ sender: Any) {
    let firstvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstcontroller") as! FirstViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstvc)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**VC2**

```
 @IBAction func presentSecond(_ sender: Any) {
        let secondtvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondcontroller") as! SecondViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondtvc)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



     @IBAction func doneAction(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

**VC3**

```
@IBAction func doneAction(_ sender: Any) {
    // Need to dismiss current and previous VC2 
}

@IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice would be to use `prepare(for segue:` at VC2 in order to send a reference of its self to VC3 so you can dismiss it later.

- So first of all add a reference variable in VC3

  ```
  var vc2Ref: VC2!
  ```
- Then in VC2 you can set this variable's value like this

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if let vc3 = segue.destination as? VC3 {
          vc3.vc2Ref = self
      }
  }
  ```
- And now you are able to dismiss VC2 and VC3

  ```
  @IBAction func doneAction(_ sender: Any) {
      //dismiss current VC3
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      //dismiss previous VC2 
      self.vc2Ref.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

Comment: getting crash by this line  `self.vc2Ref.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

About [dismiss() method document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss).

> ### Discussion
>
> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

In brief, if a presented stack is as following,

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

// A.present(B), then B.present(C), ... , D.present(E) 
// E is top-most view controller.
```

If call `E.dismiss()`, then the stack will be

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

Then, if call `C.dismiss()`, then stack will be

```
A -> B

// NOTE:
// Don't call `E.dismiss()`, `D.dismiss()`, `C.dismiss()` in sequence.
// ONLY call `C.dismiss()`. Just as the `Discussion` said.
```